# What's the criteria of deleting item?

Tags: factor-analysis, reliability, item-response-theory, item-analysis

What's the recognized criteria in statistics world?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is closely linked to the one found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172381/acceptable-values-for-discrimination-parameter-2pl-irt-model/219237#219237) relating to the magnitude of slopes in order to determine if an item contributes a meaningful amount of information (I assume you meant to say *standardized factor loadings* rather than *Cronbach's alpha < .3*). Basically, if an item correlation is too low with the latent trait being measured then it's likely of little use, and if an item has too high of a guessing parameter then the same occurs as well (too many low-ability individuals can answer an item correctly seemingly just by chance).

Comment: I just need a recognized criteria, maybe citation paper.

Comment: +1. However note that we can't be sure the OP meant factor loadings. They were speaking about alpha anyway. The very question was quite unclear to me.

Comment: @WhiteGirl: last time I checked, there is none -- especially _statistically_ speaking. Closest to what you're looking for, from a test development point of view, is the TIMMS2007 technical report. Otherwise consult Handbook of test development (2nd Ed), chapter 20, Item Analysis for Selected-Response Test Items. But AFAIK both are not discussing benchmarks for guessing parameters.

Comment: @Tom,it's so strange, why not recognized standard in statistics world??

Comment: Because there is no single 'statistics world', there is just statistics applied in various disciplines/domains?  Because rules of thumb aren't particularly strong arguments for choosing courses of action?